Leading them a long chase
I stumbled across the construction "leading them a long chase" in a 1933 newspaper children's story. Here's the whole paragraph:

Far from the old barn where Reddy and Mrs. Reddy had found what they
had thought was a safe retreat under the floor, Mrs. Reddy sat where
Reddy had left her on a sheltered slope hours ago. For a long time she
had lain curled up to rest, but all the time her sharp ears had been
set to catch the sound of the baying Dogs following Reddy’s trail.
Sometimes they passed out of hearing. Reddy was leading them a long
chase. Sometimes the barking would abruptly cease. Then Mrs. Reddy
would grin. She knew that Reddy had fooled those Dogs with one of his
smart tricks.
--The Harrisburg Telegraph, Harrisburg, PA, Feb. 17, 1933, page 14 (and several other newspapers that day). The author is Thornton W.
Burgess.

Google knows of a few other old instances where the word "on" is omitted compared to how we would put it today--"leading them on a long chase". When did that way of putting it fall out of favor? Was it the most common way of putting it back then? Or was including the "on" always the more common way?

Your link is behind a paywall. Please put the relevant quote here in the question.

See 'give it me' / 'write me' for 'she led them a merry dance', which is surely a deleted-preposition construction (and perhaps the only expression of its kind ever met with nowadays). Searching in-house for preposition deletion is also instructive.

@Barmar I've replaced the link with the quote.

Ah, as TH suggests. 'lead someone a dog's life'  is also idiomatic.

To lead [someone] a chase is natural. On got traction rather late in the game (the 21st century). Have a look at Google Books Ngram Viewer for lead * a chase,lead * on a chase (click the bubbles below the graph to see usage).
Here’s the use of lead we’re looking at:

lead verb1
I. To conduct.
I.7. to lead (a person) a dance: transferred and figurative, to put to the trouble of hurrying from place to place; hence, to compel to go through a course of irksome action. to lead
(a person) a chase: lit. to give (a pursuer) trouble by one’s
speed or circuitous course; also figurative. Also (by association
with sense II.12) to lead a person a life. a1545–
[selected attestations for dance, chase, and life] a1616   Why he’s able to leade her a
Carranto. —W. Shakespeare, All’s Well that ends Well (1623) ii. iii.
44 1861   He..often leads them a fine chace
over hill and dale. —Temple Bar December 53 1892
  How can the captain so forget himself as to lead them a paper
chase? —Cornhill Magazine July 15 1892  
She had led him the life of a dog. —Sunday Magazine August
509/2 Source: Oxford English
Dictionary (login required)


"On got traction rather late in the game (the 21st century)." Okay, narrowly speaking wrt this exact idiom. But that hides the fact that on has been in the picture since the Middle Ages. It's just been shuffled around a lot. It used to reside with the verb. Historically, the verb was an leading or on leading, and later it got A-prefixed to become a-leading. English has been playing an extended game of Whack-a-mole with its prepositions. "thus on an indictment for treason for leading on a riotous mob..." - William Maudesley, 1866.

@Tinfoil Hat Thanks, this is very helpful. But 21st century, really? As a 1965 model I've been around long enough to know that "leading them a long chase" (vs. "on a long chase") would have been a very unusual and awkward way of putting it at least as far back as the early 1970s. I can imagine some members of the elderly generation of my childhood putting it that way, as many of them had some odd ways of putting some things, but no younger. Did you mean 20th century? I see that all your examples are 19th century.
